# How can i get IE credentials to use in my code?

Tags: c#, screen-scraping, webrequest

I'm currently developing an IE plugin using [SpicIE](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SpicIE).

This plugin does some web scraping similar to the example posted on MSDN:

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create ("http://www.contoso.com/default.html");

request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse ();

Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream ();

StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (dataStream);

string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd ();

reader.Close ();
dataStream.Close ();
response.Close ();
```

However, when i run this code i receive the following error message:

> The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.

I'm currently working behind a proxy server and used the **NetworkCredential** class to manually provide my network credentials

```
request.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("name", "password", "domain");
```

but i still receive the same error.

Even if my problem is solved, i know that some users of the plugin will be behind a proxy server.

**I want to know how i can get IE credentials and use it in my code to assign it to request.Credentials**.

Maybe something like this:

```
request.Credentials = IE.DefaultCredentials;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're setting the credentials for the *site*, but you need credentials for the *proxy*.

Set [`request.Proxy.Credentials`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.iwebproxy.credentials.aspx).

(Also, use `using` statements for the response/stream/reader rather than manually closing them, otherwise they'll leak when an exception is thrown.)

EDIT: For instance, to use the default credentials for the proxy as well:

```
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try that, but what's really important to me is how to use IE credentials in my code. Can you help me in this regards?

Comment: Um, yes - set request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials