# Bing Maps Silverlight Control: How do I Display the Sun's Footprint?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, bing-maps, astronomy

I have the Sun's latitude, longitude, and altitude but I don't know how to display the Sun's footprint in a particular time as in 
http://www.karhukoti.com and 
http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/sunearth.html.

Can someone please help?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I downloaded the source code for [JSatTrak](http://www.gano.name/shawn/JSatTrak/) and tried to implement the **drawFootPrint** and **getFootPrintPolygons** with no luck.

Comment: you need to go back and evaluate the answers to your questions, and mark the ones that are correct - especially questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/752108/how-can-i-get-ie-credentials-to-use-in-my-code/752130#752130) answered by Jon Skeet. Correct answers get some added reputation, its just one of the ways this site works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not natively a part of Bing Maps - you have to program it in yourself. But from the looks of it, it appears all you need is an algorithm to determine the width/height and angle of the foot print (well, probably the darkness instead) and then just have an animation on a path geometry to move it.

Comment: Thank you @TLCo but actually I'm having trouble with all what you have mentioned. Can you please see the Edit in my original question.